# Reducing GPU memory consumption of tensor flow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get the code in this git rep working: https://github.com/cvikasreddy/skt
The training data is a 7mb text file. 
I have a Nvidia GTX 750ti with 1gb of memory. When I try to train on this machine, the trainer crashes because of running out of memory (model size beeing 2.5gb according to the error message). Of course I understand that these cannot fit into 1gb of graphic memory. 
The default settings are:

```
num_layers = 3 # Number of layers of RNN
num_hidden = 128 # Hidden size of RNN cell
batch_size = 128 # Number of sentences in a batch
seq_length = 35 # Length of sequence
```

I already tried changing them to:

```
num_layers = 3 # Number of layers of RNN
num_hidden = 128 # Hidden size of RNN cell
batch_size = 1 # Number of sentences in a batch
seq_length = 35 # Length of sequence
```

I also tried changing seq_length but this also doesn't work. What suggestions do you have to solve this problem? Of course buying a bigger graphic unit would work. But I wonder if anything in the code itself can be done. Maybe splitting the input data? The computer itself has 16gb of ram, that should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run everything on the CPU by adding

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
```

and the correct indentation before the definition of your graph. It'll be slower but you should have more than enough memory. You could also put most of your ops on the CPU, and choose a few to put on the GPU. You'll find some help for that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu).

You can also reduce the network size (`num_hidden` and `num_layers`), but your performance will decrease. If the RNN ops are done in 64 bits, maybe you can change to 32 bits, I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Thank you! Yes running on CPU is an option, in that case however memory use is still very high, about 12-16gb, one epoch taking roughly 5 hours means that it might take a month to compute the model. However it is not impossible. :)

Comment: Yes I did so, on CPU the network is able to learn, yet the resource demand is very high with one epoch taking roughly 5 hours. But I guess it is just due to the fact that it is a very big network.